# How to customize problem details in .net core 2.2 for exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I want to handle different type of exceptions in .Net Core API project and return custom error response. 
For example, Authorization Error, Internal Server Error, Validation Error etc., I would like to throw common custom errors.

For this I am thinking of customizing ProblemDetails.

Internal Server Error Response as below,

```
var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
            {
                Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Instance = feature?.Path,
                Title = isDev ? $"{ex?.GetType().Name}: {ex?.Message}" : "An error occurred.",
                Detail = isDev ? ex?.StackTrace : null,
            };
```

For Authorization the error response is like below,

```
 return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header.");
```

And for Data not available in Database, the response is like below,

```
return NotFound();
```

I use custom middleware to handle Internal Server error,

```
[Route("/error")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public ActionResult Error([FromServices] IHostingEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var ex = feature?.Error;
            var isDev = webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
            {
                Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Instance = feature?.Path,
                Title = isDev ? $"{ex?.GetType().Name}: {ex?.Message}" : "An error occurred.",
                Detail = isDev ? ex?.StackTrace : null,
            };

            return StatusCode(problemDetails.Status.Value, problemDetails);
        }
```

since each return response type is different format, those who consuming my Web API requested me for common response type with custom message. How to do that? Any Idea? How to bring all different type response/custom error like Authorization, Invalid request, internal server error etc.,

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your **custom model** and return it. Model can have **StatusCode**(1**,2**,3**,4**,5**) , **ResponseMessage** ("*internal server error*","*resurse not fount*", etc) and **body** (your object). Any request you can response **OK(customModel)**

Answer (score 0):

You can return Problem function. As follows,

```
return Problem(
  title: "my exception title",
  statusCode: 403,
  detail: "more exception info"
);
```